# Which type of non-basic cipher works better with microcontroller which has no interface and keyboard connected to it?

Tags: encryption

Did a C++ code on Caesar Cipher to do encryption and decryption with my XMC4500 microcontroller but my lecturer said that Caesar Cipher is too simple. He wants me to use a non basic type of cipher and to include size of bit length of plain text and cipher text, secret and public message number and key. And the problem is no keyboard or display interface will be connected to my microcontroller so i could not use printf, scanf, cout and cin to input any of those values. Any ideas on what Cipher I should use and how I could do it?

UPDATE: Thank you for all the suggestions but my supervisor finally told me to use ASCON instead.

Comment: Can't you upload a key?

Comment: Do you know if you can use symmetric or asymmetric encryption (or both)? *'secret'* and *'public message number'* sounds like asymmetric cryptography...

Comment: What are you trying to _do_, beyond implement cryptography?  If you just want some cryptodoohickey, I dunno, you could pick up Gimli or something small like that, but it doesn't mean much on its own without a goal that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can use both symmetric or asymmetric encryption. My lecturer only asked me to implement cryptography into my microcontroller, when I asked for more information, he would just avoid the question or would just reply that I will know it soon.

Comment: That chip is loaded with comms possibilities but yes, micro controllers tend not to have keyboards nor displays. Might this be better addressed on the electronics.stackexchange.com forum. Or at least review the datasheet.  You can run anything you like crypto wise, that's not a problem.  Sounds like the comms is going to be more of an issue for you.

Comment: Do you have to implement your own primitives, or are you just supposed to implement some application of cryptography primitives?  Maybe you can just import munacl, or libhydrogen, or strobe, and do something with one of those?

Comment: I think this question is way too broad. You need to specify more information, such as what the maximum acceptable ROM and RAM footprints are, and what throughput you want to achieve. You also need to specify whether or not you _just_ need a single, non-authenticated cipher, or a complete cryptosystem (an _authenticated_ cipher with a key exchange mechanism). If "non-basic" simply means not absolutely trivial, then RC4 (considered broken by modern standards) could do, as it is extremely simple.

Answer (score 1):

That's a 32 bit ARM chip (M4), but without any hardware based crypto capabilities. That means that the best choice of a cipher is one that runs best on 32 bit CPU's, e.g. ChaCha20, SOSEMANUK or NORX (taken from [this answer by Thomas](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52961/1172)). Of course for transport security you may want to use authenticated encryption, but you can always bold that on (this seems to be an assignment after all).

Above ciphers are good ciphers to try to implement yourself. However, if there are ciphers available in libraries then you may want to use those and safe yourself a lot of time. Before implementing a cipher, make sure that this is the purpose of the assignment!

Note that a cipher in itself does not offer security. You need a security design for your system for that.